# How to parse JSON query from ON CONNECT

Tags: objective-c, json

I have this json

```
[
  {
    "tmsId": "MV004613580000",
    "rootId": "9756367",
    "title": "2 Guns",
    "titleLang": "en",
    "descriptionLang": "en",
    "releaseYear": 2013,
    "runTime": "PT01H49M",
    "showtimes": [
      {
        "theatre": {
          "id": "5658",
          "name": "Regal Fenway Stadium 13"
        },
        "barg": true,
        "dateTime": "2013-08-06T10:00",
        "ticketURI": "http://www.fandango.com/tms.asp?t=AAOVD&m=126005&d=2013-08-06",
        "quals": "Descriptive Video Services|RPX|No Passes or Super Savers|Stadium Seating|Closed Captioned"
      }
```

Under showtimes I want to save the "id" and "name" attributes into NSStrings variables.

Any suggestions into how to approach the JSON?

Comment: I'd suggest a parser.  You have your choice of about a dozen different ones.  See json.org.

Comment: Possible parsers: [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit), and [JSONModel](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel), are a few examples.

Comment: Yes I do used NSJSONSerialization, and I already have my data into in an array. The question would be how to navigate through it to get to the information I need.

Comment: Once parsed, you can access like you would any other object. So, in your case, the JSON starts as an array, so the JSON parser will return an NSArray(Mutable depending on reading options). For reference, JSON arrays are parsed to NSArrays, objects are parsed to NSDictionaries, Strings are parsed to NSString.

Comment: And NSLog each object you extract, so you can figure out your progress.  In an NSLog an array is bracketed with `()` while a dictionary is bracketed with `{}`.  And `=` is used to separate dictionary key and value.  Otherwise (with a few minor variations) it looks exactly like the original JSON.

Comment: (Someone could -- and probably will, eventually -- come along and tell you exactly what statements to use to extract the data you say you want above, but then you learn nothing.  It's easy to figure out if you try, so try.)

Answer (score 0):

NSJONSerialization methods return NSArrays or dictionaries. You can browse through the dictionary for the json property you need. Properties in a json object turn into key-value pairs in a dictionary.